# How do I make my website display a horizontal scrolling bar when it is minimized?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I made a 'practice' website and haven't really grasped mobile optimization. Instead, I want to take a different approach which many websites do do. I want my site to display a horizontal scrolling bar on the bottom of the page if and ONLY if the site is minimized. All my element sizes are in percentage quantities and even all my divs has a style of 100% height and width. I also want all the elements to stay the same in position and none to shift around or disappear. For my case, whenever my site is minimized the following happens:

- Everything (images, text, etc) shrinks to fit in the smaller screen size.
- Some elements disappear while others overlay it. (For example, when there is a row with two 'col-md-6' columns from bootstrap, it looks all fine at normal size, but when minimized, one of the columns becomes enormous and the other column seizes to exist.
- < br >s within text distort the flow of the paragraphs.

I have tried:

```
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

as a style for body, html, and div(separately, not at once)
but that just disables the vertical scrolling and elements further down are not seen. And even then, the auto overflow-x thingy doesn't solve it

I have also tried:

```
min-width: 800px;
```

and that creates the horizontal scroll but still some elements are lost, and it seems the horizontal scroll is only long enough ONLY so that you can scroll to view the entire nav bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site will be trying to adjust to a mobile viewport, you can prevent this by adding:

```
<head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable = no">
</head>
```

Or try

```
<head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

The problem is likely with your viewport tag.

You will also need to set a fixed width on the body.

Comment: Didn't really change anything.. it changed some of the layout distortedness that happens but still most of the issues stand. I should still keep that as before I had a mobile device width in 'content'.

Comment: I think in tandem with my answer you would need to set a width for the body tag as this will otherwise be arbitrary. Try adding body{width:1800px;} to your CSS and see if this helps.

Comment: That worked! Well, for the most part. Except now, since my resolution is lower (I'm guessing) every elements shifts to the right (by a lot). Should I make the width less or make a min-width?

Comment: Yes try setting a min-width, this is not an easily document-able scenario (and not really recommended in general) but if you need to play around and see what works best.

Comment: Ok fixed that and now it works flawlessly. Thanks! Except one problem remains: one of the columns in the row (made with Bootstrap) disappears randomly when the scroll bar is introduced. Do you happen to know why that is and how to possibly fix that?

Comment: Off the top of my head no but feel free to set up a JSFiddle and i will take a look.

Comment: Maybe set up a new question for that, as this one seems to be resolved?